# Issue with compound character font rendering in openGL using FTGL

Tags: c++, opengl, unicode, combinations, ftgl

In my application, FTGL renders unicode characters of *true type fonts* well **except compound characters**. Compound character is a combination of unicode consonant and vowel sounds.

For example, in an indic language Tamil,  the following string input

**"கா கி கீ கு கூ கெ கே கை கொ கோ  கௌ"**

is displayed as

[image: "tamil compound characters in openGL"]

in the **openGL viewer**.

***output of some characters is not same as input.***

Can anybody help on this?

my code snippet,

```
    std::ifstream fontFile("latha.ttf", std::ios::binary);//tamil unicode font
    if (fontFile.fail())
        return NULL;
    fontFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::fstream::pos_type fontFileSize = fontFile.tellg();
    fontFile.seekg(0);
    unsigned char *fontBuffer = new unsigned char[fontFileSize];
    fontFile.read((char *)fontBuffer, fontFileSize);        

    FTBitmapFont* m_pFTFont = new FTBitmapFont(fontBuffer, fontFileSize);
    m_pFTFont->Render("கா கி கீ கு கூ கெ கே கை கொ கோ  கௌ");
```

Comment: FTGL has no support for complex scripts, of which Tamil is one example.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of "[complex text layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout)". Enjoy your stay ;)

To put it simply, a script that uses complex text layout does not have a simple 1:1 mapping between Unicode codepoints and the glyph to be rendered. And Tamil is such a script.

FTGL only handles scripts that have simple layout, because complex text layout is *complex* (very much so). So it's not going to be able to reproduce Tamil script correctly.

You will need to use a layout engine like [Harfbuzz](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/) to layout your text. FTGL can still render the script, but you'll need Harfbuzz to tell you which glyphs in the font to render.

Comment: Thank you Nicol for a quick one. I will try Harbuzz.